# Mule: Invoking a flow multiple times with different parameters

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I have this code to refactor which contains multiple flows all doing the same tasks. Planning to modify it as a generic flow executed in an iterative way with different start parameters. How can i achieve this in mule.

```
ex:
<flow name="flow1">
    <db:select/>//some specific query for retrieval from  database
    <expression-component/> Exceutes some specific method of spring bean
</flow>
```

Similar to flow 1 there are numerous flow which does the same  logic retrieves data from some table and execute a bean method on basis of query . How can i refactor this code to a generic flow so that it executes iteratively with initialized parameters(table name , method to execute).

Comment: Do you want to execute different sql queries coming from different flows from a same db component ??

Answer (score 0):

1.There is no need of making it generic you'll end up with same number of nodes which share same db connection

2.for making it generic 
  2.1 create a flow variable with same name before calling this flow(where ever yo are calling)
  2.2  flow variable value has the query 
  2.3  access the flow variable value in

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can create a subflow that will have the DB component, and this subflow will be invoked from different Mule flow and execute the DB component which will use a flow variable that contain dynamic SQL queries .. something like the following :-

```
<db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration">
  <db:dynamic-query>#[flowVars.selectQuery]</db:dynamic-query>
  </db:select>
```

Here `#[flowVars.selectQuery]` will be filled with different SQL queries from different flows